# How to get all layered navigation filters available

Tags: admin, layered-navigation, filter

I have been looking a way to get all the layered navigation filters available, i dont know if this is per category or if i cant get all of them, because i need them on the admin side to choose in each category which ones  i want to use, but currently i have been just able to get them in the front end when a category is selected by this line:

```
 $appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State')->getActiveFilters();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to get all attributes that are set as filterable via the admin section then you need to filter on the table `catalog_eav_attribute` where the column `is_filterable` is true:

```
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Collection $attributeCollection */
$attributeCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
$attributeCollection->addFieldToFilter('is_filterable', true);
```